# Appending dictionaries in list to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array of dictionaries with the same keys and I already have a pandas template with the df headers with me. I need to loop through the array and append each dictionary to the df.

```
arr_dics = [{'event':'alpha', 'site':'beta', 'date':'gamma'}, {'event':'a', 'site':'b', 'date':'c'}] 

for i in range(len(arr_dics)):
    new_dic = arr_dics[i]
    two_games_df.append(new_dic, ignore_index=True)
```

However the output I get only appends the second dictionary to the dataframe.
Do I need to specify the index somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your confusion, note that `append` is not `inplace`. So you need to assign the output of the `append` function to the original `df`:

```
two_games_df=  two_games_df.append(new_dic, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: How do I use inplace?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible. This is the only way out! Does it help?

Comment: Nevermind! It worked! I just wanted to know for future usage. Thanks

Comment: Okay... Consider upvoting and accepting the answer too. It motivates us!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.concat`

```
arr_dic = [{'event':'alpha', 'site':'beta', 'date':'gamma'}, {'event':'a', 'site':'b', 'date':'c'}] 
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['event','site','date'])

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(arr_dic)])
df
   event  site   date
0  alpha  beta  gamma
1      a     b      c
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
two_games_df=two_games_df.append(new_dic, ignore_index=True)
```

df.append appends rows of other to the end of caller, returning a new object and you need to save the new object.

df.append does not modify the original object.